# Convert to smalldatetime sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to find some records that match a couple of variables, they are dates.

But I get this error:
Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type

From my sql script.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetByTravelDates
(
@date_start as varchar,
@date_end   as varchar
)
AS

select * from holiday_a hr
inner join holiday_b hw on
hr.holiday_id=hw.id
where date_start=CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,@date_start,101) and date_end=CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,@date_end,101)
```

Then posting from c# control to the SP:

```
string date = "24 Jan 2014";
string date2 = "29 Jan 2014";
```

The format in the DB is like:
2014-01-24 00:00:00

yyyy-mm-dd

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain why, if you have datetime fields, you pass strings and try to convert them in the SQL Procedure? It seems wrong from the start. Change you procedure to require two smalldatetime and pass two datetime from your C# code

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define the size of the varchar as:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetByTravelDates
(
@date_start as varchar(15),
@date_end   as varchar(15)
)
```

if error exist then check the data type of your `date_start.`

Comment: Yes, but why? explain why declaring the size should work

Comment: @Steve: coz If you declare a variable of type varchar without specifying a length, the default length is 1  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic416897-8-1.aspx

Comment: That's the reason to complete the answer

Comment: OR better yet: if those are **dates** - use an appropriate datatype like `DATE`, `DATETIME/DATETIME2(n)` or `SMALLDATETIME` instead of a string in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

Change your SP parameters from

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetByTravelDates
(
@date_start as varchar,
@date_end   as varchar
)
AS
```

to

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetByTravelDates
(
@date_start as varchar(15),
@date_end   as varchar(15)
)
AS
```

Comment: Yes, but why? explain why declaring the size should work